Does SonarQube Provide Logical Lines of Code (LLOC) Metrics?
I am using SonarQube for static code analysis and need to distinguish between Source Lines of Code (SLOC) and Logical Lines of Code (LLOC) for a project. I've identified that SonarQube provides a "Lines of Code" (ncloc) metric, which counts non-commented lines, but I'm uncertain if this is equivalent to LLOC. Can SonarQube directly measure LLOC, or is ncloc the closest equivalent? If LLOC isn't directly available, what's the best way to approximate it from SonarQube's metrics? I'm looking for insights on how to accurately compare SLOC and LLOC using SonarQube for thorough project evaluation. Any guidance or methods commonly used would be very helpful.
